# Referring to a HashMap in its Context in Zig

Tags: hashmap, zig

The Zig standard library includes [`std.HashMap`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:HashMap) which expects a `Context` `type` to be provided, which is essentially just a pair of functions, `eql` and `hash`, that allow the hash map implementation to determine properties about the keys it is storing. The context type may look like

```rust
const Context = struct {
    pub fn eql(self: Context, a: T, b: T) bool {
        ...
    }

    pub fn hash(self: Context, k: T) u64 {
        ...
    }
};
```

As can see above, Zig allows the two functions to refer to each other via the `self` argument.

However, I would like to have the equality function depend on the value associated with the given key and not just the key itself. In order for this to happen, the `eql` function must refer to the implementing hash map itself.

**Is there a way to refer to the hashmap in the equality function in Zig?**

For example, this might look something like

```rust
const Context = struct {
    pub fn eql(self: Context, a: T, b: T, table: HashTable) bool {
        ...
    }

    pub fn hash(self: Context, k: T, table: HashTable) u64 {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: `the equality function depend on the value of the keys and just the key itself ... the eql function must refer to the implementing hash map itself` - this makes no sense to me. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @sigod Sorry, there was a typo. I meant "not just the key itself". I edited the question.

Comment: @sigod I want the equality function to be able to reference the hashmap so it can actually `.get` the value using the given key and compare using that.

Comment: I don't think it supports that use case. Such `eql`/`hash` implementations don't make sense for a hash map.